# Automatically update a summary page from different pivot tables in excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a few sheets in an Excel workbook. Each sheet contains a pivot table. I then have a summary sheet that contains columns from each of these pivot tables. An example of the original raw data looks like this:

[image]

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Time</th><th>Desc</th><th>Temp</th><th>Prg_Freq</th><th>Meas_Freq</th><th>Test 1</th><th>Test 2</th><th>Test 3</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:36</td><td>Band1</td><td>25​</td><td>136.0125</td><td>491.325168</td><td>-159.729</td><td>-159.451</td><td>-165.363</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:37</td><td>Band1</td><td>25​</td><td>150.35</td><td>491.325172</td><td>-159.829</td><td>-158.704</td><td>-165.39</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:37</td><td>Band1</td><td>25​</td><td>174</td><td>520.000181</td><td>-158.598</td><td>-158.107</td><td>-165.383</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:37</td><td>Band1</td><td>-30​</td><td>136.0125</td><td>567.300203</td><td>-152.966</td><td>-152.551</td><td>-161.758</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:37</td><td>Band1</td><td>-30​</td><td>150.35</td><td>979.325345</td><td>-153.232</td><td>-152.462</td><td>-160.635</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:37</td><td>Band1</td><td>-30​</td><td>174</td><td>1075.425379</td><td>-151.84</td><td>-151.679</td><td>-161.582</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:38</td><td>Band1</td><td>50​</td><td>136.0125</td><td>1150.35041</td><td>-151.03</td><td>-151.667</td><td>-161.282</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:38</td><td>Band1</td><td>50​</td><td>150.35</td><td>1259.300445</td><td>-151.793</td><td>-150.713</td><td>-157.757</td></tr>
 <tr><td>5/1/2020 11:38</td><td>Band1</td><td>50​</td><td>174</td><td>1308.725461</td><td>-152.012</td><td>-150.948</td><td>-158.31</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Where I can usually change which Test to display, either Test 1, Test 2 or Test 3.  Here is an example of the pivot table formed showing Test 1 data:

[image]

```html
<style type="text/css">
 table.tableizer-table {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 } 
 .tableizer-table td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 .tableizer-table th {
  background-color: #104E8B; 
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: bold;
 }
</style>
<table class="tableizer-table">
<thead><tr class="tableizer-firstrow"><th>Sum of Test 1</th><th>Column Labels</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody>
 <tr><td>Row Labels</td><td>25​</td><td>-30​</td><td>50​</td><td>Grand Total</td></tr>
 <tr><td>136.0125</td><td>-159.729</td><td>-152.966</td><td>-151.03</td><td>-463.725</td></tr>
 <tr><td>150.35</td><td>-159.829</td><td>-153.232</td><td>-151.793</td><td>-464.854</td></tr>
 <tr><td>174</td><td>-158.598</td><td>-151.84</td><td>-152.012</td><td>-462.45</td></tr>
 <tr><td>Grand Total</td><td>-478.156</td><td>-458.038</td><td>-454.835</td><td>-1391.029</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I then have a summary sheet, showing data from each tab based on the Test being selected. The cells in the summary sheet is a simple =TabCell. I want to show the same Test # on the summary sheet from each sheet. However, in order to do so, I have to go through each sheet and update to the same Test # to display in each of the sheets, in order to correctly update the summary sheet.

[image]

Is it possible to update the summary sheet to show if I select Test 1 (for example), that all the pivot tables on each sheet gets updated with the Test 1 filter, which in turn updates the summary page with just the Test 1 data?

If it is possible, how to go about doing this? Can it be done via a formula in the summary sheet or do I need a VBA script?

Any help will be sincerely appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the pivot well? What is in the Values and what is in the filters? Are you dragging the field "Test1" into both? And when you want to see Test2, you drag Test1 out and drag Test2 in???

Comment: @teylyn, Thanks for your solution.  I have updated the post with the fields as per your suggestion.  I do drag Test 1 out and then drag Test 2 in to display the Test 2 pivot chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you normalize your data table to contain a column for Test number and another column for test value, you can build a pivot table that has all tests visible. You then don't need to change the pivot table definition to show a different test, and you can use the GetPivotData function to pull the data from the pivot table dynamically.

[image]

Power Query can quickly transform your table into a normalized table.

You may also be able to create the summary result without using a pivot table at all. With the given data sample, the summary can be done with a few SUMIFS functions.

Edit: steps to create the normalized table with Power Query

- select the source data
- on the Data ribbon, click **From Table / Range**
- The data is converted into an Excel Table and loaded into the Power Query editor
- Select the first five columns, i.e. all columns, except the three test columns
- click Transform > Unpivot > Unpivot other columns
- rename the Attribute column to "Test number"
- on the Home ribbon, click "Close and load"

Comment: Hello, I use office 365, I am not sure if there is a Power Query that I can use to transform my table??  Is there an option available in Office 365 to transform the data?

Comment: Yes. It is called "Get and Transform" on the Data ribbon. The green table in my screenshot was created from your data with a few clicks in Power Query. No writing code, no writing formulas.

Comment: I added the steps for Power Query to my answer.

Comment: Sincerest thanks for teaching me about this Power Query.  I have been using excel for a very long time and this is the first time I have come across this feature.  Thank you!

Comment: Power Query is the best thing that happened in Excel in the last 20 years. It's been around as an add-in for 2010 and 2013 and got built into the main application with Excel 2016. Very powerful!!